# Public/private keys from using keytool to generate certificate/keystore

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I'm reading about using the `keytool` command to generate a certificate from the [oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/step2.html). The part I don’t understand is it says after running the command `keytool -genkey ...`, it creates a public/private key. Can someone tell me explicitly what and where the public/private keys are? The only part I understand is after running the command, it creates an entry in the keystore…

Comment: Yes, it creates an entry in the keystore containing the public and private keys.

Comment: @EJP I know I can get the public key by doing `-exportcert`. But what is the private key and how do I view it?

Comment: It's in the KeyStore. You can view it with keytool -list -v.

Comment: @EJP I believe you can only view the public cert with keytool -list -v. There's no way to view the private key except by programatically.